# Child component not loading correctly in ngFor (but updates after resizing windows)

Tags: angular, highcharts, angular-material, ngfor

I am using mat-grid and injecting charts in grid elements (mat-card) for a custom dashboard.

The number of cards is not fixed but depends on a certain data array.

The grid is constructed using cardLayout to define number of rows/columns of each card.
It works fine when not using ngFor.
But for some reason, the ngFor loops breaks the layout at init; any resize solves this.

I am unsure what's happening - screenshots and code are below.

[Screenshot after init - the first card is not using ngFor and loads correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vbgNn.png)

[Screenshot after Resizing - all cards update correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RsFG8.png)

**dash.ts - cardLayout definition**

```
  cardLayout = this.breakpointObserver
    .observe([Breakpoints.Handset, Breakpoints.TabletPortrait])
    .pipe(
      map(({ matches }) => {
        if (matches) {
          return {
            columns: 1,
            miniCard: { cols: 1, rows: 1 },
            chart: { cols: 1, rows: 2 },
            table: { cols: 1, rows: 4 },
          };
        }

        return {
          columns: 4,
          miniCard: { cols: 1, rows: 1 },
          chart: { cols: 2, rows: 2 },
          table: { cols: 4, rows: 4 },
        };
      })
    );
```

**dash.html**

```
<div class="grid-container" *ngIf="indicatorsData.length > 0">
  <!--ngIf is used to delay initialization of child components while waiting for input data-->
  <mat-grid-list cols="{{ (cardLayout | async)?.columns }}" rowHeight="150px">
    <!--Charts-->

    <mat-grid-tile
      [colspan]="(cardLayout | async)?.chart?.cols"
      [rowspan]="(cardLayout | async)?.chart?.rows"
    >
      <!--Here child component (app-highchart-example) loads correctly and is responsive with parent container app-card!-->
      <app-card
        [title]="indicatorsData[0].name!"
        [description]="indicatorsData[0].desc!"
      >
        <app-highcharts-example [indicator]="indicatorsData[0]!">
        </app-highcharts-example>
      </app-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>

    <mat-grid-tile
      *ngFor="let indicator of indicatorsData"
      [colspan]="(cardLayout | async)?.chart?.cols"
      [rowspan]="(cardLayout | async)?.chart?.rows"
    >
      <!--app-highcharts-example not responsive - it does not seem to take app-card container into account 
            BUT: updates correctly after resizing the windows !
          -->
      <app-card [title]="indicator.name!" [description]="indicator.desc!">
        <app-highcharts-example [indicator]="indicator">
        </app-highcharts-example>
      </app-card>
    </mat-grid-tile>
  </mat-grid-list>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

`breakpointObserver.observe` does not trigger at component init, only on window resize. You may have to trigger a fake window.resize to force its init.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer.
I tried adding a  window.dispatchEvent(new Event('resize')); in init without success.
However, I think it's not the issue because if I replace each (cardLayout | async)?.chart?.rows and (cardLayout | async)?.chart?.cols with a fixed value (such as 2). The issue remains

Comment: You also use other values, so you would have to remove all `(cardLayout | async)` in the HTML (so in you `mat-grid-list` too, and where you use minicard) in order to test that theory. Have you already done that ?

Comment: Hey, yes I did remove all `(cardLayout | async)` including the one in `mat-grid-list` - still without success.

If that can help, the problematic element `</app-highcharts-example>` is a mat-card-content of the `app-card` passed as :

 `<mat-card-content"><ng-content></ng-content></mat-card-content>`

Comment: Hmmm, actually I often have similar issues with charts, when their container has no size. I think what happens is that you init the chart in a 0-sized block, then the block gets a size from somewhere (parent, child ?), and the charts does not update to this new size. To check this you may add some hard-coded size to your app-card (`min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px;`) and see what happens ?

Comment: Yes !! Thanks you're on to something there, it does affect where the child (chart) component is initially rendered. So how do I solve this? I guess I should either find a way to delay initialization of charts or a way to force update charts afterwards ?

Comment: Yeah, that's the idea. Maybe add `width/height: 100%` on your tags. You may also try adding a ng-container before mat-grid-tile: `<ng-container *ngIf="(cardLayout | async) as cardLayoutSync">`, and then use cardLayoutSync inside, instead of an other `| async`. This way ou should be sure the grid layout is synchronous...

Comment: Thanks a lot, I tried both ideas and still not working - I am struggling so I might be doing something wrong...
Other infos:
in *card-component* template I use FxFlex:  
 `<mat-card-content fxFlex="75%"><ng-content></ng-content</mat-card-content>`

I also have this selector in **highcharts-example.component.scss**

`highcharts-chart { width: 100%;  height: 100%; display: block;}`

Finally, I also have: in **card-component.css**:
'.dashboard-card {  position: absolute;  top: 15px;  left: 15px;  right: 15px;  bottom: 15px;}`